# reset an iOS gesture by button click

Tags: ios, gestures

I have an application that allows a user to pan and zoom in on an image.  I think that, without too much trouble, the user can get themselves into a state where they are zoomed in to one portion of the image, and would want to reset everything back to the 'ground state' (ie, bring all the translation and rescaling back to 0 and 1, respectively).

I'm doing translation by:

```
- (void)panGestureRecognized:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
  CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.view];
  recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x + translation.x,
                                   recognizer.view.center.y + translation.y);
  [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:self.view];
}
```

And this works fine, I can translate the image.

If I press the button, I want to be able to change the translation back to 0,0.  One way to do this would seem to be to store the gesturerecognizer and set that back to zero, as in:

```
mPanRecognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(mPanRecognizer.view.center.x,
                                   mPanRecognizer.view.center.y);
[mPanRecognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0,0) inView:self.view];
```

Where mPanRecognizer is a member variable storing the recognizer.  However, doing this produces the following log information, with no actual behavioral change:

```
Ignoring call to [UIPanGestureRecognizer setTranslation:inView:] since gesture recognizer is not active.
```

So how can I reset the gesture to be translating to 0,0 by pressing a button?

Comment: Not too familiar with this, but isn't it possible to just set the bounds of the view in the code explicitly, without having to use the gesture recognizer at all?

Comment: @GeneralMike-- not sure what you mean.  It was my understanding that the gesture recognizer is where the actual translation/scaling values are stored (from the user's gesture), and the consequences as well.  Or am I reading the API wrong?

Comment: Again, I've never had to do this before, but if you want to return to the default state, couldn't you just do `[self.view setBounds:CGRectMake(0,0,width,height)];` where `width` and `height` are whatever the dimensions of your device are (I think that's the syntax anyway)?

Comment: I thought the gesture recognizer was just to allow the user to interact and control the size of the screen.  But developers have access to the code itself, so we don't need the gesture recognizer to do what we want.  That's my understanding anyway, but I may be wrong.

Comment: @GeneralMike-- it looks like I can us that approach for scaling.  Not sure about translation yet, still going. Trying imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity; does nothing useful.

Comment: @GeneralMike-- yeah, so 
  [imageView setBounds:CGRectMake(0,0,imageView.superview.bounds.size.width,imageView.superview.bounds.size.height)]; works for rescaling.  Nice.  Now for the translation, then it's looking done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done without using gesture recognizers.  To set the scaling, use

```
[self.view setBound:CGRectMake(0,0,width,height)];
```

where `width` and `height` are the dimensions of your device.

To set the translation, use

```
[self.view setCenter:CGPointMake(width/2.0,height/2.0)];
```

To set your width and height easily, contain your view in a separate UIView.  Have that UIView anchored properly and in the proper z-order, then you can modify the above lines to be

```
[imageView setBounds:CGRectMake(0,0,imageView.superview.bounds.size.width,imageView.superview.bounds.size.height)];
[imageView setCenter:CGPointMake(imageView.superview.center.x, imageView.superview.center.y)];
```

thereby avoiding the need for storying of any points or magic numbers specific to a particular device.